# Finite intersection property and a family of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_k \rightarrow x$ be a convergent sequence in a Metric Space. Let $A_i$ be a family of closed sets with the property that for each $A \in A_i$, there is an $N$ such that $k \geq N$ implies $x_k \in A$. Prove that $ x \in \cap A_i$.

My attempt:

Suppose by contradiction that $x$ is not in  $\cap A_i$, then there exists some $i$ for which $x \notin A_i$, and for which there is an $N_i$ such that if $k \geq N_i$, then $x_k \in A_i$. Considering the sequence $\{x_j\}_{j=N_i}^{\infty}$, this is a convergent sequence inside of a closed set converging to an element outside of the set, a contradiction. Hence $x \in \cap A_i$.

The problem I am having is that this proof does not use the finite intersection property (and it is an exercise in a chapter concerning that topic), so I feel like I am missing something. Any hints or insight appreciated.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this proof. You used the assumption that's given to yield the result. If you wanted to leverage theory about the finite intersection property, you could prove the fact that the finite intersection of sets with the property that the ${A_i}$ have has the same property, but your proof works and does not use this approach.

Comment: Presumably $x$ is supposed to be the limit of $(x_k)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey yes will add that.

Comment: By  $k \geq i$, you mean  $k \geq N_i$. Right?

Comment: @Ramiro yes sorry will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct.  Note that you don't have to phrase it as a proof by contradiction: you can just directly use the sequence starting at $N_i$ as you did to show that $x$ is in each $A_i$.

This result is certainly related to the finite intersection property and could come up in arguments involving it.  For instance, you could use this statement as a lemma to prove that if a countable family $(A_i)$ of compact sets has the finite intersection property, the intersection is nonempty.  Namely, for each $k$ choose $x_k\in A_1\cap A_2\cap\dots\cap A_k$.  By compactness, you can pass to a subsequence and assume that this sequence $(x_k)$ converges to some point $x$.  The result above would then give that $x\in \bigcap A_k$, so the intersection is nonempty.